# how to support multiple formats when passing date through to service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I'm having an issue supporting multiple formats for a date input that is submitted from my view.

For example, if a user submits a date of birth as 03/04/2016 it parses and works just fine.

I need to allow the user to submit as above, or as 3/4/2016, or even as 342016.

This is how I have it set to convert and send as part of my payload in my controller.

```
DateOfBirth: (new Date($scope.dob)).toJSON()
```

As I said above, works fine when using 03/04/2016 format, but I need to support if a user enters other ways as well.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is three difference input boxes an option? (day, month, year). There is no magic solution for those kind of things, so most of the time you ask the user to enter the date in a specific format. You could try to parse the input in lot of ways, but you will never know all the formats the user will use.

Comment: `<input type=date>` is pretty nice in most places, and would give you a consistent output. it should still work as a text input in old browsers, and that's no worse UX than what you have going it sounds like...

Comment: It may be easier to check if the date is in the form x/y/zzzz or xx/yy/zzzz and force the user to fix it if it's not. It gets significantly more complicated to allow xyzzzz or xxyyzzzz (or xyyzzzz). Better yet as soon as the user enters 2 digits you can enter the / for him.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. How can you tell what 2122016 means? Is it 21/2/2016 or 2/12/2016 ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this lib

[MOMENT.JS](http://momentjs.com/)

Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in JavaScript.

```
moment().format('L');    // 03/04/2016
moment().format('l');    // 3/4/2016
moment(any date).format('DDMMYYYY') // you can to combine format output
moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

OR [UI-MASK](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask/master/demo/index.html)

Comment: I think the asker wants a consistent way to convert any input string (in formats like dd/mm/yyyy or d/m/yyyy or dmyyyy or ddmmyyyy) to a date object so he can get a consistent format to pass to the server. You're providing the other way around in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may work if there are delimiters in the date.

```
var regEx1 = /^(\d?\d)[\/\.\-](\d?\d)[\/\.\-](\d\d\d\d)$/; //Catch the regular way  
var matches = regEx1.exec($scope.dob);
if (matches && matches.length >= 4) { 
   DateOfBirth: (new Date(matches[3],matches[2],matches[1])).toJSON()
} else {
    alert("Invalid date, please don't forget the delimiters");
}
```

If there aren't delimiters in the date I don't think there's a general way to deal with this unless the date is exactly 6 or 8 digits long.